# Sum the next value of hash in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes like this:

```
[{Mon, 09 May 2016 14:49:17 UTC +00:00=>12}, 
{Sun, 17 Apr 2016 14:08:40 UTC +00:00=>30}, 
{Sun, 16 Apr 2016 14:08:40 UTC +00:00=>18}, 
{Sun, 15 Apr 2016 14:03:33 UTC +00:00=>21}]
```

How can I sum the previous value from the oldest date to the current date, my expected output will be:

```
[{Mon, 09 May 2016 14:49:17 UTC +00:00=>81}, 
{Sun, 17 Apr 2016 14:08:40 UTC +00:00=>69}, 
{Sun, 16 Apr 2016 14:08:40 UTC +00:00=>39}, 
{Sun, 15 Apr 2016 14:03:33 UTC +00:00=>21}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why is it an array of hashes in the first place?

Comment: I have a balance field in my model, but I want to get the accumulative balance, is there a better way to calculate it before i extract to hashes? Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't work. I get: `syntax error, unexpected ','`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the key of every hash in your array is a `DateTime` object, you can get what your want with this:

```
balance = [
  {DateTime.parse('Mon, 09 May 2016 14:49:17 UTC +00:00')=>12}, 
  {DateTime.parse('Sun, 17 Apr 2016 14:08:40 UTC +00:00')=>30}, 
  {DateTime.parse('Sun, 16 Apr 2016 14:08:40 UTC +00:00')=>18}, 
  {DateTime.parse('Sun, 15 Apr 2016 14:03:33 UTC +00:00')=>21}
] # => your original array     

# Get expected array.
balance.map{ |h| 
  { 
    h.keys.first => balance.select{ |e| 
                      e.keys.first <= h.keys.first }.map{ |s| 
                        s[s.keys.first] }.reduce(:+) 
  } 
}
```

I split the code in lines in order to improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to `sort` the array first and then use the `map` function to keep a running total to collect the required data.

```
# sort the balances by date
balance = balance.sort {|a, b| a.keys.first <=> b.keys.first }

# get running total and collect for each date
total = 0
balance.map do |entry|
  date, value = entry.first
  total += value
  {date => total}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your array is in lastest-to-earliest date order and looks something like `arr` below:

```
a = [{ "Mon, 09 May 2016 14:49:17 UTC +00:00"=>12 }, 
     { "Sun, 17 Apr 2016 14:08:40 UTC +00:00"=>30 }, 
     { "Sun, 16 Apr 2016 14:08:40 UTC +00:00"=>18 }, 
     { "Sun, 15 Apr 2016 14:03:33 UTC +00:00"=>21 }]

require 'date'
arr = a.map do |h|
  (d, v) = h.to_a.first
  { DateTime.parse(d) => v }
end
  #=> [{#<DateTime: 2016-05-09T14:49:17+00:00 ((2457518j,53357s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>12},
  #    {#<DateTime: 2016-04-17T14:08:40+00:00 ((2457496j,50920s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>30},
  #    {#<DateTime: 2016-04-16T14:08:40+00:00 ((2457495j,50920s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>18},
  #    {#<DateTime: 2016-04-15T14:03:33+00:00 ((2457494j,50613s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>21}]
```

We can then compute the required array as follows.

```
cumv = 0
arr.reverse.
    map { |h| h.to_a.first }.
    each_with_object([]) do |(d,v),a|
      cumv += v
      a << { d => cumv }
    end.
    reverse
  #=> [{#<DateTime: 2016-05-09T14:49:17+00:00 ((2457518j,53357s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>81},
  #    {#<DateTime: 2016-04-17T14:08:40+00:00 ((2457496j,50920s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>69},
  #    {#<DateTime: 2016-04-16T14:08:40+00:00 ((2457495j,50920s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>39},
  #    {#<DateTime: 2016-04-15T14:03:33+00:00 ((2457494j,50613s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>21}]
```